# How to make transition on DataContex change?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, blend

I have a simple wp7 app with 3 pages. I've made page transition to work (with built-in transitions from TransitionService (slide, rotate roll...) as shown in [this simple tutorial](http://rhizohm.net/irhetoric/post/2010/11/09/Page-Transition-Animations-and-Windows-Phone-7.aspx). On one of my phone page, I bind few different ViewModels (only one is visible). Also, there I have a button which change DataContex (visible ViewModel). All of that work perfectly. What I want to do is to input somekind of transition on DataContex change (as I have on phone page navigation), so it would appear that the user is navigating on other page. 
I appreciate any advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Christian Schormann demos creating page transitions in his Mix talk [CL02](http://live.visitmix.com/MIX10/Sessions/CL02). Download the video in high res format and play it locally will make it easy to follow.

Alternatively, you could make use of the Transition control packaged with the November Windows Phone Toolkit to do this work for you. Discussed in more detail here.

[Transitions for Windows Phone 7 - Will's Blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wfaught/archive/2010/11/15/transitions.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what you want to animate you could look at using a [`StoryBoard`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.animation.storyboard%28v=VS.95%29.aspx).

Comment: I want to slide whole page. I've never before created a storyboard... I'll give it a look. Thanks Matt.